# Select an XML attribtute of parent node with condition for child node

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xpath, xmltype

I have a XMLType column in database from which I have a condition to check for a child node text and fetch the Parent node's attribute. In the XML i need the quantity (qty="3") to be fetched when i have the ConfigId(=5621507)

My SQL:

```
select
cfg.session_xml.extract('/ns1:configurationSession/ns1:products/ns1:product/@qty',
'xmlns:ns1="http://abc.com/schema/service"')
from vz_cfg2_sess_xml cfg
where existsNode(cfg.session_xml,'/ns1:configurationSession/ns1:products/ns1:product/[ns1:configId=5621507]')=1;
```

My XML:

```
<ns1:configurationSession sessionId="3543737" xmlns:ns1="http://abc.com/schema/service" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <ns1:products>
        <ns1:product approvalCode="N" productId="ABC" qty="1">
            <ns1:configId>5229719</ns1:configId>
        </ns1:product>
        <ns1:product approvalCode="N" productId="DEF" qty="1">
            <ns1:configId>5621506</ns1:configId>
        </ns1:product>
        <ns1:product approvalCode="N" productId="DEF" qty="3">
            <ns1:configId>5621507</ns1:configId>
        </ns1:product>
    </ns1:products>
</ns1:configurationSession>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not something like this:

```
select
cfg.session_xml.extract('/ns1:configurationSession/ns1:products/ns1:product[ns1:configId=5621507]/@qty',
'xmlns:ns1="http://abc.com/schema/service"').getstringval()
from vz_cfg2_sess_xml cfg
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d6826/2)